# System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter threw an exception

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, converters, multibinding

trying to implement some code behind in my xaml document. The idea here is that the code behind will compare two values, and return True if they strings are equal, but i keep getting  System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter threw an exception

```
    <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:cvm="clr-namespace:Mashup;assembly=CompareValuesMashup"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <cvm:CompareTwoValues x:Key="CompareValues" />    
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">
                    <!-- values to be processed by the converter -->
                    <TextBox Name="value1" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBox Name="value2" Height="50" Margin="0,15,0,0" /> 
                    <!--  Compare value1 and value2-->
                    <TextBox Name="result1" Height="50" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompareValues}">
                                <Binding ElementName="value1" Path="Text" /> 
                                <Binding ElementName="value2" Path="Text" />
                            </MultiBinding> 
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

here's the code behind. I'm not sure where the exception is coming from.

```
        namespace Mashup
{
  public class CompareTwoValues
  {
    public CompareTwoValues()
    {
      base..ctor();
    }

    public bool Execute(string value1, string value2)
    {
      return value1 == value2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any information *about* the exception?  What type it is, a stack trace, etc.?

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mashup.CompareTwoValues' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompareTwoValues` doesn't implement [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It doesn't implement *any* interface or base class, so I wouldn't expect it to be usable by the framework in similar scenarios either.

It needs to implement that interface to be used by the framework:

```
public class CompareTwoValues : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public CompareTwoValues()
  {
    base..ctor();
  }

  public bool Execute(string value1, string value2)
  {
    return value1 == value2;
  }

  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // convert the values to the target type
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // convert the value back to the set of target types
  }
}
```

Currently the class *compares* values, but it doesn't *convert* anything.  It's not entirely clear from the existing class logic what that conversion would look like, but it needs to happen in order to be used in this context.

An example of converting multiple values to a single value might be something like:

```
return String.Concat(values[0], " ", values[1]);
```

And converting back might be something like:

```
return (value as string).Split(' ');
```

(If, for example, the values were strings and the desired result is a concatenated space-delimited string.)

Comment: what we are trying to do is if the content of two strings are equal, then return a single string, either yes or no.

Comment: @EMAW2008: That's not what a MultiValueConverter does.  It, well, converts multiple values into a single value and back again.  Basically a tiny serialization engine.  I'm not sure what you're intending to accomplish in the UI in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much better to implement a single ValueConverter?
like this:

```
 public class CompareValues: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
<!--  Compare value1 and value2-->
                <TextBox Name="result1" Height="50" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource CompareValues}" ElementName="value1" Path="Text">
                            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="value2"/>
                                    </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                        </MultiBinding> 
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

Comment: I'll be comparing the first value to a second string that is a comma delimited string. So I don't know if that solution is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

@david  This worked or my purposes. I needed to return a string that i can use to trigger a style.

```
   public class IsEqual : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] == "")
            return string.Format("blank");
        // returns yes if equal
        else if (string.Equals(values[0], values[1]))
            return string.Format("yes");
        //returns no if not equal
        else
            return String.Format("no");
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```